# Replacing C++ std::bind with rvalue references and varadic templates to lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, rvalue-reference

I have an function like this for an simple threadpool to enqueue an tasks on it, the following signatures are:

```cpp
        template<class Fn, class... Args>
        void Enqueue(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args);

        void EnqueueBasic(std::function<void()>&& task);
```

One for complex functions which have any number of parameters and the other is an rvalue reference for an simple function, which stores the functor into an fixed queue like this:

(Definition of EnqueueBasic)

```cpp
        _pendingTasks.push_overflow(eastl::forward<PendingTask>(task));
```

(Definition of Enqueue)

```cpp
EnqueueBasic(std::bind(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

It works perfectly fine, but i want tor replace it with lambdas, how i can replace `std::bind` to an simple lambda?, since i'm trying to learn how to C++ lambdas work, but this remained me a bit confused.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look like this. I'm using `std::invoke` (C++17) to be as generic as possible. You can replace it with a direct call if that's all you need.

```
EnqueueBasic([&]{ return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...); });
```